# Old TM data to new installed macbook

Tags: time-machine, install

For more than a year my macbook air used a time-machine (local network, synology). After completely new fresh install of my macbook air, i reconnected time machine. In TM, data before the fresh install is not shown if i enter time-machine. Only the backup made after the new install is shown. How can i access the old data? On the TM itself it looks like old and new data is merged.

Kind regards
George

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Time Machine will notice if there are existing backups on the disk you select and ask if you want to reuse the old backup data.

I haven't tried personally but looks like you can use the `tmutil` command to inherit a backup, too:

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup /path/to/backups
```

See also:  http://pondini.org/TM/B6.html

Comment: The question to reuse the old backup date I did not get. The option "browse other backup disk" (mentioned in additional link) I'll try when I get home :-)

Comment: I found out when standing in finder on root of the disk, enter TM, all backups shown in star-wars screen. Solved!